# Possible to install Linux RHEL completely offline?

Tags: rhel, system-installation

The documentation on Linux RHEL seems to assume you have a connected machine and will be installing through that connection. I need to set up RHEL completely offline using CD-ROMs only (no USB). Is this possible? If so, what is the general strategy?

Comment: What have you tried?  You should be able to do so.  https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6-Beta/html/Installation_Guide/sn-install-diff-source-x86.html

Comment: Similar [link](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6-Beta/html/Installation_Guide/s1-installationmethod-x86.html#s1-begininstall-cd-inst-x86)... seems pretty straight forward. Have you tried?

Comment: Installing RHEL is possible offline using the DVD. But then to register to the RHN network you need to be online.

Comment: Will being "unregistered" have any consequences? I cannot go online with this machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can download ISO files and burn it into a CD/DVD using specific format and continue the installation offline.

Hope below links address your issues:

https://access.redhat.com/articles/142303
http://www.redhat.com/download/howto_download.html+++#3